# Which screws go first?

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, real

[image]Humans are not always accurate at measurements. I recently got a table top that came with an attachment. Table top and attachment are nearly of same size and rectangular with four screw holes near corners to attach, although the holes are little disoriented(**same size but at slightly different positions on table top and
 attachment although they are at correct distances from each other independently**) and screws don't fit exactly into them. So should we fit the two adjacent screws first or two diagonal screws first?

(**Black one is the table top, Red one is the attachment.**)

Which one would be easier?

Comment: Is this a puzzle or simply you're puzzling on the table's installation?

Comment: @Alex, puzzling on the table's installation.

Comment: Send it back and get a refund. That overhanging corner will be a toddler hazard.

Comment: @Forklift, Already did mate lol

Comment: Bottom left attachment hole is a bit flatter, intentional?

Comment: At the risk of repeating @Alex's question . . . *is this actually a puzzle?* It doesn't seem to be at all.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [diy.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: This is an excellent real life puzzle! Again and again. Every tapping machine is calibrated and maintained to just-barely tolerable tolerances, only solvable by craftspersons. Screwdriver you, downvoters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should

> do the **diagonals** first.
>
>  If you do the adjacent side two first, even perfectly aligning the right-side screw/hole, there's a chance due to the shape of left-side's hole that you have the attachment slightly rotated in alignment vs. the table.  That will make two non-adjacent screws harder to put in.
>
>  Doing the diagonals first should avoid this, as centering the non-adjacent right-side screw/hole will keep the table and attachment aligned by limiting how much play the adjacent-left screw can have in its placement.